# how to Change colour of a particular button in gridLayout in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to make tambola coin picker with Python and Kivy and I am new to kivy.
Here, I created gridlayout buttons from 1 to 90. I want to change the color of particular button in gridlayout when its number is picked. I am facing issues to update gridlayout with new colored button. Here I am attaching my code. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRzd4.png)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout 
from kivy.graphics import Color
import random
coins = random.sample(range(1,91), 90)
#print(coins)
picked_coins=[]
current_coin=0
#print(picked_coins)
class Housie(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Housie,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.title = Label(text="Housie Coin Picker",font_size = 50,size_hint=(1, .55),pos_hint={'x':0, 'y':.45})
        self.main_label = Label(text = "Click PICK NUMBER", size_hint=(1, .60),pos_hint={'x':0, 'y':.35})
        self.picked_ones = Label(text = "picked_coins", size_hint=(1, .40),pos_hint={'x':0, 'y':.40})
        self.help_button = Button(text = "PICK NUMBER", size_hint=(.3, .1),pos_hint={'x':.65, 'y':.1},on_press = self.update)
        self.add_widget(self.title)
        self.add_widget(self.main_label)
        self.add_widget(self.picked_ones)
        self.add_widget(self.help_button)
        self.add_widget(self.userinterface())
    def userinterface(self):
        self.layout = GridLayout(cols = 10,size_hint=(.50, .50))
        for i in range(1,91):
            self.layout.add_widget(Button(background_color=(1,0,0,1),text =str(i)))
        return self.layout
    def update(self,event):
        for coin in coins:
            if coin not in picked_coins:
                current_coin=coin
                picked_coins.append(coin)
                self.main_label.text = str(coin)
                for i in self.layout.children:
                    if i.text == str(coin):
                     #What to do Here?
                break
        self.picked_ones.text = "Picked coins = {}".format(" ".join(str(sorted(picked_coins))))
class app1(App):
    def build(self):
        return Housie()
if __name__=="__main__":
     app1().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind a method to each `Button` like this:

```
def userinterface(self):
    self.layout = GridLayout(cols = 10,size_hint=(.50, .50))
    for i in range(1,91):
        self.layout.add_widget(Button(background_color=(1,0,0,1),text=str(i), on_release=self.butt_pressed))
    return self.layout

def butt_pressed(self, button):
    button.background_normal = ''
    button.background_color = (1,0,0,1)
```

Th `butt_pressed()` method changes the background color of the pessed `Button`.